# Service required a bean of type Repository that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm calling the Repository in my Service

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=BookingRepository.class)
public class BookingService {

    private final BookingRepository bookingRepository;
```

this is my Repository interface

```
package repositories;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import models.Booking

public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {
}
```

i had this error when running the application:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in services.BookingService required a bean of type 'repositories.BookingRepository' that could not be found.
```

Comment: The problem is in packages structure.

Comment: how to fix that

Comment: Can you shou the packages structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Spring-Boot` then you can use `@Repository` annotation to create `BookingRepository` bean like this:

```
@Repository
public interface BookingRepository extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {

}
```

Then use `@Autowired` annotation for field injection or use constructor injection in BookingService like this:

```
@Service
public class BookingService {

    @Autowired
    private BookingRepository bookingRepository;

}
```

`Constructor injection` (spring-boot will automatically inject the constructor here)

```
@Service
public class BookingService {

    private final BookingRepository bookingRepository;

    public BookingService(BookingRepository bookingRepository) {
        this.bookingRepository = bookingRepository;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation you are using is the right one. However it will only work properly with a configuration class.

**Solution**

Put the `@ComponentScan` annotation to the main application class. This is the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Alternatively (preferred be me) you can omit this annotation and just fix your package structure. Spring scans for components by default starting from the package of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and including all its sub-packages.